# Set "Check In Comment" Document Library (C#, CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, csom

It is possible for the code (C#, CSOM) to add a comment to field "**Check In Comment**" (_CheckinComment) when saving the latest version of document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify it when you use the `file.CheckIn()` method `file.Publish()` method as mentioned below:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/test/Shared Documents/abcd.txt");

context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery();    

if (file.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
{
   file.CheckIn("my comment", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
}

file.Publish("My comment on published document");
context.ExecuteQuery();
```